# How to debug with gdb when using exec functions

Tags: linux, debugging, exec

How to debug when using exec functions? For example, I set a breakpoint at this line `execl("/home/hel/a.out", "a.out", arg1, arg2, NULL);`How can I debug a.out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a separate debug session, like this:

```
$ gdb /home/hel/a.out
(gdb) run arg1 arg2
```

Isn't this obvious?

Comment: In the fork-exec, sockpair is called and one of the file descriptor fd is passed to exec as an argument. I want to keep the file descriptor open and call sendmsg() to write that unix domain socket. Can I debug a.out when using exec?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! Have you checked this: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html ?